# Why must all inputs to AES be multiples of 16?

Tags: aes, pycrypto

I'm using the PyCrypto implementation of AES and I'm trying to encrypt some text (24 bytes) using a 24 byte key.

```
aes_ecb = AES.new('\x00'*24, AES.MODE_ECB)
aes_ecb.encrypt("123456"*4)
```

I get this surprising error `ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length`
So why is it that my input must be a multiple of 16? It would make more sense to me that the input string length must be a multiple of my key size, because this would allow nice bitwise operations between the key and blocks of plaintext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AES is a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher). Quote from the Wikipedia page: “a block cipher is a deterministic algorithm operating on fixed-length groups of bits”.

AES can only work with blocks of 128 bits (that is, 16 chars, as you noticed).

If your input can have lengths others than a multiple of 128, depending on your application, you may have to be extremely careful how you handle [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#Padding).

Comment: Then under the hood, AES pads my key so that it is a multiple of 16?

Comment: @Mark It is the input that must be a multiple of the block size, not the key. AES allows keysizes of 128, 192 and 256. The encryption of one block is not a simple XOR between key and block, it is more complex and does not require the block size to be the same as the keysize.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add info about mods of operations

Yes, AES is a 128-bit (16-byte) block cipher with multiple possible key length (128, 192, 256), but the cause of this text padding limitation (and error msg) is ECB [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). ECB is the simplest of the encryption modes. I don't know your goals, so will just skip the part that **it doesn't provide serious message confidentiality**.

CBC and CTR are more common and usually appropriate to use and in CTR mode you don't need 128-bit message length.

There is also [ciphertext stealing (CTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing) method for ECB and CBC modes.

> Method of using a block cipher mode of operation that allows for
>   processing of messages that are not evenly divisible into blocks
>   without resulting in any expansion of the ciphertext, at the cost of
>   slightly increased complexity

But Ciphertext stealing for ECB mode requires the plaintext to be longer than one 128-bit block.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [block size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_(cryptography)) is 16 bytes, the way to handle this is to [add padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) when encrypting.