# How to fix 'invalid ciphertext size' error in Javascript ? (aes)

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, vue.js, aes

I'm trying to decrypt data using a key and the AES-JS library.
Whenever I put a 16 bytes key I get the following error:

> Error: "invalid ciphertext size (must be 16 bytes)"

I already tried to change the key to non-16 bytes value but then I get this error:

> Error: "invalid key size (must be 16, 24 or 32 bytes)"

Here is my code so far :

```
export const getEventBlockData = (cm, eventBlockData) => {
  const encryptedBlockBuf = Buffer.from(eventBlockData, 'base64');
  const aes = new aesjs.AES(aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes('1111111111111111'));
  const decryptedBlockBuffer = new Buffer(aes.decrypt(encryptedBlockBuf));
};
```

The part that generates an error is the last line with `aes.decrypt(...`

NB : the cm var is supposed to be the key but for testing purposes i replaced it by a string "1111111111111111" and the eventBlockData is the buffer i'm trying to decrypt, he has the following form :

```
Event Block Data :{"type":"Buffer","data":[49,56,53,50,55,51,53,49,50,50,48,48,48,49,48,48,48,48,49]} cm-service.js:61
Encrypted Block buff :{"type":"Buffer","data":[49,56,53,50,55,51,53,49,50,50,48,48,48,49,48,48,48,48,49]}
```

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error says `invalid ciphertext size (must be 16 bytes)`, so the problem is not with your `key` and changing the `key` length, like you said you did in your post, won't resolve the problem as it doesn't concern the key.

It's a common and known **[issue](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js/issues/16)** that concerns **[the length of plaintext in CBC](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js/issues/16)** and it occurs when you use a cipher text with length other than a multiple of 16 bytes.

To solve this you need to add a [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#Padding) for your encrypted text, for further details you can read **[Why must all inputs to AES be multiples of 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773450/why-must-all-inputs-to-aes-be-multiples-of-16)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'v read the padding wikipedia page but i'm still a bit lost on how to do it.
If i understood correctly i need to add bytes to my buffer : 

"Encrypted Block buff :{"type":"Buffer","data":[215,206,118,239,126,117,219,109,52,211,93,52,211,77]}"

in order to make it a multiple of 16.
But i dont know where to start or which pattern to use for the bytes.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Quentin_otd I am sorry, I don't really have a better knowledge on this issue with `aesjs`, I encountred the same thing when I was writing it in Java, and I tried to provide an answer based on the few articles I read.

Comment: Not really. Any valid AES-CBC ciphertext will have length that is a multiple of 16 bytes. Therefore his ciphertext is corrupted in some way. It has nothing to do with padding.